# No such file or directory [sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h]

Tags: sensor-msgs, rosmake, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, guys,
I have been writing some codes that made use of geometry_msgs lately. The way I included them in the previous algorithm was like this:

```
#include "geometry_msgs/Point.h"
```

And now I would like to use LaserScan.h, located in my system at

```
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/sensor_msgs
```

using

```
#include "geometry_msgs/Point.h"
```

The thing is, when I try to compile what I get is this error, showing it can't find it:

```
  /home/alonsoj1/ros_workspace/prueba/src/talker.cpp:2:48: error: common_msgs/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h: No such file or directory
```

That's why I just link to the whole path like this to make it work:

```
#include "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
```

I wonder why this is necessary, since the file Point.h (the one I used before wasn't in geometry_msgs/ path directly, but in /opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/geometry_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/geometry_msgs). Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12916/no-such-file-or-directory-%5Bsensor_msgs/laserscan.h%5D/) by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2012-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check your package's manifest.xml. It must say the following:

```
<depend package="geometry_msgs" />
<depend package="sensor_msgs" />
```

This will allow CMake to locate the appropriate header files. The other thing to check is to make sure that `geometry_msgs` is properly located in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on 2012-02-07**:
Awesome, exactly what was going on. I had forgotten about manifest.xml dependencies.